# Reply with template while keeping email trail

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking for a solution where a group of people would be able to reply to emails using templates that are located within the shared folder. The one thing I can't seem to figure out is a way to use this template to reply to emails while still keeping the email trail/thread. Attaching the email is not an option because of managements requirements. Anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this?

One option that was suggested was to use the email signature function and put the templates in there, but that is a last resort as it's difficult to maintain and update.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
Private Sub ReplyToWithTemplate()

Dim currItem As Object
Dim myitem As Outlook.MailItem

Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem

If TypeOf currItem Is MailItem Then
    Set myitem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("H:\test\test.oft")
    myitem.To = currItem.Reply.To
    myitem.HTMLBody = myitem.HTMLBody & currItem.HTMLBody
    'myitem.body = myitem.body & currItem.body
    myitem.Display
End If

Set myitem = Nothing
Set currItem = Nothing

End Sub
```